# What is the relationship between Bundler and Rails applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can someone please describe what is Bunder and what is its role?

Comment: http://gembundler.com/rationale.html

Comment: @Arman apart from the above link a good source of information whould be this video `http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts/rails3/bundler-action-mailer` describing bundler importance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bundler is a ruby gem which is used to Manage your application dependencies. It can be called gem management system.
When you are developing Rails project with multiple people, and those people have different version of gem installed in their PC, bundler is very helpful in this case. When you run `bundle install` bundler will look for the specific gem version you are using in your project, if it doesn't have the correct version, bundler will install that gem automatically, if it does, bundler will use the existing gem for your project. It makes all PC used to develop the project use the same version of ruby gems.